# jquery mobile Listview format columns

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I was wondering if it's possible to format a listview like the picture below.  I would like to be able to re-size the images and I need the text lines to be centered.  The COL descriptions also need to be centered.  Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ability to resize images? Do you want different image sizes in each list item so that column widths are different on different rows? Do you want end user to resize images by dragging a corner?

Comment: Hi @ezanker, I just want to be able to change the image size if necessary.  For example say the icon is 40x40 px, but I only want the height of the row 30 px.  I want to be able to modify the CSS property to shrink the height to 30 px.  I do not want the end user to modify the size of the images and all rows will be the same size.(once I figure out what height the image will be)

Comment: Seems that my previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903951/adding-an-additional-image-on-the-right-of-listview-element-in-jquery-mobile does exactly what you want. If you need a different image size, just tweak the CSS according to my instructions in the answer... Is that not what you need?

Comment: @ezanker I can't believe I missed that >_<  Thank you for pointing that out.  One last thing, can the dividers be formatted like I have in the picture?  for example I want Col 1 to be aligned to the left, Col 2 (centered), and Col 3 to be aligned to the right.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In the answer Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y41zcz6w/5/ the images are aligned left and right and the text is aligned to the middle. What in the fiddle is not right?

Comment: @ezanker Your example in the fiddle is correct, what I mean is the **"list divider"** not the actual items. Something like this
<li data-role="list-divider">col1  col2  col3</li>  The list divider does not need to show pictures it will just be text, however I need col1 to be aligned to the left, col 2 to the center and col 3 aligned to the right.

Comment: There are better ways, but here is a pretty easy way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/y41zcz6w/7/